# Appending/Prepending a vector to a TableForm

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting

How do i Append(Prepend) to a List?

```
A = {{a,b},{c,d}} // TableForm
B = {x, y}
MapThread[Prepend, {A,B}]
```

does not work. If i leave out the TableForm it does. This could be solved by converting TableForm of a List back to a list which works:

```
A = {{a,b},{c,d}}
B = {x, y}
MapThread[Prepend, {A,B}]
```

But how do i do such if A allready is in TableForm? Should i generally allways avoid outputting as TableForm if the structure contains data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MapAt[MapThread[Prepend, {#, B}] &, A, {1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution myself:

```
AList = A[[1]]
```

and hence

```
A = {{a,b},{c,d}} // TableForm
B = {x, y}
MapThread[Prepend, {A[[1]],B}] // TableForm
```

since ListForm is just a Head. This way most heads can be detached.

Comment: What I usually do in my code is add parentheses, "( A = {{a,b},{c,d}} ) // TableForm" so it keeps lists as lists, but I can see it in TableForm, or MatrixForm, or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should define A without `//TableForm`

```
A = {{a,b},{c,d}}  
B = {x, y}
Transpose[Join[{B},A]] (* or Thread[Join[{B}, A ]]*)
(*{{x, a, c}, {y, b, d}}*)
```

Comment: This circumvention of the issue was allready mentioned in the question. I looked for a solution which does this on TableForms etc. I was able to solve it myself after having posted the question hence i answered myself.

Comment: Sorry for trying to give you a helpful answer.

Comment: @Gladaed You are going to make yourself very unhappy by sticking to wrapping things into `TableForm`.